# Is IDatabase.CreateBatch equivalent to redis-cli --pipe?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I've ran into a situation where using `redis-cli --pipe` is feasible, but I may need too much work to make `redis-cli` available into some container.

Thus, I'm not sure if what `redis-cli --pipe` does is almost what StackExchange.Redis may do with `IDatabase.CreateBatch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of *batch* is something which does not pertain to Redis but, rather to StackExchange.Redis and its multiplexed architecture: it mainly allows to send a sequence of commands through a multiplexer with the guarantee of not having any other command external to that sequence sent in-between those ones.

On the other side, `redis-cli --pipe` uses [Redis pipelining](https://redis.io/docs/manual/pipelining/): StackExchange.Redis allows to use that by simply making use of the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern, as you can read in its [documentation](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers.html#pipelining).